# How can i implement my own version of the Auction House program of Metaplex?

Tags: anchor, metaplex

I want to create an auction mechanism with Gated access to my NFTs how can i do that.

Answer (score 3):

The Auction House program has a really cool feature called auctioneer that gives control to some other program to execute the functions of the Auction house contract. The Auction House contract uses instant sale but as you want to gate the access to some functions through NFT than you can create your own Anchor program and do CPI to the auction house program with added features that you want to build in your contract. To learn more about it you can check this [here](https://docs.metaplex.com/guides/auction-house/auctioneer)